# How to remove grub on startup

Tags: boot, grub

I've a single OS pc, with latest version of elementary installed on. Everytime I start up the system, Grub asks me to select what to boot or it will select automatically in 30 second the first row (and that's the right one btw)... is there a way to remove this step?
thank you so much

btw this is my grub file:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` and set the line `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.0`

You need to set 0.0 instead of 0 because the grub developers wanted to avoid any problem caused by people disabling grub that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. changing GRUB_TIMEOUT to decimal and

```
sudo update-grub
```

didn't make a change.

Does anybody face the same problem.
I'd like to have the elementary splash at startup and boot directly into login mode.

my /etc/default/grub contains these active lines:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Answer (score 0):

When Grub detects a *failure* it will automatically use a 30 second timeout, ignoring the value of `GRUB_TIMEOUT`.
There is a variable to override this, `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT`, [described here](https://askubuntu.com/a/244752/1117671).
You can set this variable to the value of `GRUB_TIMEOUT` in `/etc/default/grub` as shown below.

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
```

Then just update Grub.

```
sudo update-grub
```